# Apache htaccess - How to rewrite URL to include the page's ad name value?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a dedicated server running CENTOS 6.9 x86_64 xen hvm, cPanel & WHM 64.0 (build 15), Apache 2.4.25 and PHP 5.6.30.

My website's .htaccess file currently includes the following and is working as expected:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Since I am inexperienced with mod_rewrite and PHP, I need assistance with the following:

My website contains profile pages of different models.
An example of a current model profile URL is written as such:

http://www.mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=123

I would like the URL to be re-written instead as:

http://www.mywebsite.com/profile/123/model-ad-name-here

In order to display (within the profile.php page) the model's ad name, I have the following code:

```
        <?php require_once('cms/includes/init_files.php');?>

        <?php

        $id = getParam('id');
        $query_string = "SELECT * from profiles where id='$id'";
        $query = $db->query($query_string);
        $data = $db->fetch_assoc($query);

        ?>
```

... and to display the ad name value within the profile.php page itself, I use the code:

```
       <?php echo ucfirst($data['ad_name']); ?>
```

1) What would I need to add to the .htaccess file to re-write the URL to my desired format mentioned above and ...

2) Is there any special code I would need to edit/add to the profile.php page in order to help assist with this?

I appreciate any expert assistance you may provide regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Your can add a rewrite rule as shown below.

This will rewrite `profile/123/model-ad-name-here` to `profile.php?id=123` to make your pretty url work. This rule will only work with numeric IDs and the `model-ad-name-here` is ignored.

This is very basic URL rewriting. You can read up on [URL rewriting for beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/) and [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and do it yourself in the future.

No edits to you pages are required except that all links to the profile will have to be updated to the new URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# This rewrites 'profile/123/model-ad-name-here' to 'profile.php?id=123'
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+) profile.php?$1 [L]
```